# javascript - Capturing console with line number

Tags: javascript, console.log, nw.js, nwjs

How do I capture the line number of logs when capturing the console?
*(Chrome only - other browsers not relevant for me)*

I have the below to capture all logs;

```
consoleLogs: [],

init: function(){
    app.captureConsole();
},

captureConsole: function(){
    var _log = console.log;

    console.log = function() {
        app.consoleLogs.push(JSON.stringify({method: 'log', args: arguments}));
        return _log.apply(console, arguments); // <-- line number 123 [e.g.]
    };
},
```

When the console is returned the line number for all consoles is 123 as expected - this isn't important. What I want is to be able to push the original console log number to my array.

It is a nw.js app so a chrome api / nw api would be great [if it exists]

Comment: What do you mean line number? Line number of the code that called `console.log`? Or the index of the log inside `consoleLogs` array?

Comment: Line number of the code console log was called at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to parse the value of `new Error().stack`. It is a string which is the stack trace of the scope where the `Error` object was created.

The output is browser dependent since it is a non-standard feature. Since you only need it to work on nw.js it could be an option for you.

On node.js (and I suspect chrome) the output is a newline separated string where each line is of the format:

```
at functionName (/absolute/file/path:lineNumber:charNumber)
```

So the in your case the information you want is probably:

```
new Error().stack.split('\n')[1];
```